# Split an array into multiple arrays by condition

Tags: python, arrays

I have an 1D array of values eg.

```
ind = array([1,200,1999,2333,5000,....],
      dtype=int64)
```

and I want to split this array where the first array contains values <2000 and the next array contains values between 2000 and 4000 etc.

I don't want to split by nth number of arrays but rather by the condition where each array contains the values based on the condition.

The outcome should look like:

```
[array([1,200,1999], dtype=int64),array([2333], dtype=int64),array([5000,...], dtype=int64),...]
```

I tried `np.split(ind, [2000,4000])`

and also tried defining a split function

```
def split(arr, cond):
  return [arr[cond], arr[~cond]]
```

and calling

```
for i in range(2000,3026000,2000):
    split(ind, ind<2000+i)
```

but both methods doesn't seem to work...

Sorry I'm new on python and stack overflow so the formatting is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

# get an increasing array
arr = np.random.randint(0, 400, size=50).cumsum()

bracket_size = 2000
brackets = np.arange(0, arr.max() + bracket_size, bracket_size)
# array([    0,  2000,  4000,  6000,  8000, 10000])

result = np.split(arr, np.unique(np.searchsorted(brackets, arr), return_index=True)[1])
# [array([], dtype=int64),
#  array([ 172,  219,  336,  528,  851, 1102, 1297, 1656, 1665, 1876]),
#  array([2153, 2395, 2687, 2774, 2844, 2932, 3328, 3642, 3835, 3874, 3961]),
#  array([4135, 4223, 4560, 4725, 4750, 5083, 5155, 5420, 5535, 5778, 5975]),
#  array([6310, 6648, 6747, 6924, 7167, 7452, 7599, 7746]),
#  array([8144, 8432, 8697, 8882, 9009, 9041, 9072, 9274, 9518, 9669])]
```

You can first compute an array of "brackets" that specifies where each element of your array should go. Then, you can assign each array element to the correct bracket using `np.searchsorted`. Since `split` expects a list of indices where the arryay should be split, one can use `np.unique` to find the first index where a split for each bracket should occur.